# How to find sum of field in a table using ORMlite

Tags: android

MODEL

```
 public class HouseHoldIncome implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1299751771198967848L;

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField
private String incomecategory;



@DatabaseField(columnName = "date", dataType = 
DataType.DATE_STRING,format = "MM-dd-yyyy")
private Date date;

@DatabaseField
private int content;

@DatabaseField
private float sum;


 @DatabaseField(foreign = true,foreignAutoRefresh = true, canBeNull = 
 false,
        index = true)
private Category category;


public HouseHoldIncome() {

}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}




public int getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(int content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public float getSum() {
    return sum;
}

public void setSum(float sum) {
    this.sum = sum;
}


public String getIncomecategory() {
    return incomecategory;
}

public void setIncomecategory(String incomecategory) {
    this.incomecategory = incomecategory;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}


public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

DATABASE MANAGER

```
  public  List<HouseHoldIncome>getAllHouseholdincome(Date from,Date 
to) {



        List<HouseHoldIncome> houseHoldIncomes = new 
        ArrayList<HouseHoldIncome>();
        try {
            Dao<HouseHoldIncome, String> dahouseholdincom = 
 dbHelper.getDaoHouseHoldIncome();


    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    GenericRawResults<HouseHoldIncome> rowresults=

    dahouseholdincom.queryRaw("select date,sum(sum) from HouseHoldIncome 
   where date between '01-01-2015' and '12-31-2015' group by date",
                    new RawRowMapper<HouseHoldIncome>() {
                        @Override

    public HouseHoldIncome mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] 
     resultColumns) {
                            return new 
    HouseHoldIncome(df.parse(resultColumns[0]),
    Float.parseFloat(resultColumns[1]));
                        }
                    });

            rowresults.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.get().e(GreenAgriApp.getInstance(), 
     e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return houseHoldIncomes;
    }
```

The Query is returning empty result though while running it manually in SQLite database browser returns results.

On debugging the value  size = 0 for the result is shown.

Could any one please let me know where Have I gone wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because u are using the condition and group by on the same column 'date'. try removing the group by clause first.